# How to convert list of tuples into list of strings with no commas

Tags: python, string, tuples

How do I convert the list of permutations into something that simply is:

`['HELLO SAMPLE STRING SET', 'HELLO SAMPLE SET STRING' ...]`

i.e. for each item in the list of tuples, I would like to make the separator a space rather than comma, and also make it a simple string, not a tuple?

I have tried to use .join but it hasn't been effective.

Example:

`strings = ['HELLO', 'SAMPLE', 'STRING', 'SET']`

`permutations_str = list(permutations(strings))`

This produces the below, but would like it as above.

`[('HELLO', 'SAMPLE', 'STRING', 'SET'), ('HELLO', 'SAMPLE', 'SET', 'STRING'), ('HELLO', 'STRING', 'SAMPLE', 'SET'), ('HELLO', 'STRING', 'SET', 'SAMPLE'), ('HELLO', 'SET', 'SAMPLE', 'STRING'), ('HELLO', 'SET', 'STRING', 'SAMPLE'), ('SAMPLE', 'HELLO', 'STRING', 'SET'), ('SAMPLE', 'HELLO', 'SET', 'STRING'), ('SAMPLE', 'STRING', 'HELLO', 'SET'), ('SAMPLE', 'STRING', 'SET', 'HELLO'), ('SAMPLE', 'SET', 'HELLO', 'STRING'), ('SAMPLE', 'SET', 'STRING', 'HELLO'), ('STRING', 'HELLO', 'SAMPLE', 'SET'), ('STRING', 'HELLO', 'SET', 'SAMPLE'), ('STRING', 'SAMPLE', 'HELLO', 'SET'), ('STRING', 'SAMPLE', 'SET', 'HELLO'), ('STRING', 'SET', 'HELLO', 'SAMPLE'), ('STRING', 'SET', 'SAMPLE', 'HELLO'), ('SET', 'HELLO', 'SAMPLE', 'STRING'), ('SET', 'HELLO', 'STRING', 'SAMPLE'), ('SET', 'SAMPLE', 'HELLO', 'STRING'), ('SET', 'SAMPLE', 'STRING', 'HELLO'), ('SET', 'STRING', 'HELLO', 'SAMPLE'), ('SET', 'STRING', 'SAMPLE', 'HELLO')]`

Comment: `result = ' '.join(tuple)`

Comment: Hello mountainwater, I don't know much about python per se, but if I understand your question correctly, is this an answer to your problem? https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-convert-string-to-tuple/  Sorry I can't provide a better answer, I'm not knowledgeable enough on python as I said before. I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks! I tried that link but Mark's answer below solved it perfectly.

Comment: Okay great, @mountainwater , remember to tag Mark's answer as the solution. Greets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `join()` each of the permutations. You can do that with a simple comprehension like:

```
from itertools import permutations

strings = ['HELLO', 'SAMPLE', 'STRING', 'SET']

results = [" ".join(s) for s in permutations(strings)]
```

results:

```
['HELLO SAMPLE STRING SET',
 'HELLO SAMPLE SET STRING',
 'HELLO STRING SAMPLE SET',
 'HELLO STRING SET SAMPLE',
 'HELLO SET SAMPLE STRING',
 ...
 'SET STRING SAMPLE HELLO']
```

Comment: Thank you that's exactly what was needed